# Fullscreen of an iframe on mobile devices

Tags: html, iframe, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have got an iframe. Inside this iframe I have a player, which can go into fullscreen. Everything works fine on desktop browsers, but it does not works in chrome on a tablet nor in mobile safari on an iPhone, but it works in mozilla firefox on a tablet. Is it possible to let the iframe go fullscreen in chrome and safari on mobile devices?

Here is, how I set the iframe:

```
<iframe src='http://www.bader-kuperman.de/v3/pics/j-ch103346black/img3d_000051.html' border='0' width='620' height='465' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' frameborder='0' style='float:left; margin-left:0px' allowfullscreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true'></iframe>
```

Here is the website, where I integrated the player through an iframe.

http://www.bader-kuperman.de/de/collection/497/91/just/ch1033/black2014-09-17-21-15-01_-detail

Hope u could give me some advices.

Comment: maybe https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios will help

Comment: Here is a recent article from Chris Coyier that I found interesting: https://blog.codepen.io/2017/12/01/stupid-iframes-stupid-ios/

Answer (score 7):

To cover the entire viewport, you can use:

`<iframe src="PAGE" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
</iframe>`

That will fill the entire page or part you want to fill.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using some Inline Styling to reset the borders and set the height and width manually.

```
<iframe style = "display: block;border: none;height: 100vh; width: 100vw;"; src='http://www.bader-kuperman.de/v3/pics/j-ch103346black/img3d_000051.html' border='0' width='620' height='465' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' frameborder='0' style='float:left; margin-left:0px' allowfullscreen='true' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true'></iframe>
```

---

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qegaezk6/69/